# apache cxf-codegen-plugin wsdl2java ignore WSDL options

Tags: cxf, maven-plugin, wsdl2java

I need to generate java code from two wsdl files. The pom.xml below works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.luvva</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <cxf.sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</cxf.sourceRoot>
        <cxf.version>3.4.2</cxf.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.wsdl</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The problem is that these wsdl files declare some elements with the same name and namespace. So, one of them overwrites the other during code generation. I tried the following pom.xml, but all the configuration is simply ignored.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.luvva</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-test-2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <cxf.version>3.4.2</cxf.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/vw_proposals.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-P</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>http://www.vwfsbr.com.br/servicebus=br.com.vwfsbr.proposals</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/vw_tables.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-P</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>http://www.vwfsbr.com.br/servicebus=br.com.vwfsbr.tables</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How can I make the plugin work properly? I also tried -autoNameResolution and packageNames. Nothing works, it's as if the configuration were being ignored.

The wsdl files are available [here](https://app.bancovw.com.br/WsCCOSvc_v2/Proposta.svc?singleWsdl) and [here](https://digital.bancovw.com.br/WsFrontEndSystemSvc/TabelasSvc.svc?singleWsdl). (Use the command below to download them).

```
curl [link] >> [fileName]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the plugin was executed directly, the configuration was being ignored.
When the plugin ran during the maven generate sources phase, the configuration was not ignored and it worked just fine.